# How to const_cast a vector of const pointers to a vector of non-const pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, const-cast

I have a function that's looking for an element inside a custom list implementation. To make it const-correct, I can do this neat overload and even use a one-liner to reuse the very same implementation, thus not having to duplicate logic.

```
const MyObject* findObject(const MyList& list)
{
  //...
}

MyObject* findObject(MyList& list)
{
  return const_cast<MyObject*>(findObject(const_cast<const MyList&>(list)));
}
```

The problem is, what do I do once I need to return multiple element pointers inside a vector barring unsave/non-portable hacks like reinterpret_cast?

```
std::vector<const MyObject*> findObject(const MyList& list)
{
  //...
}

std::vector<MyObject*> findObject(MyList& list)
{
  // this is sth I'm looking for:
  const_element_cast<std::vector<MyObject*>>( findObject( const_cast<const MyList&>(list)) );
}
```

Comment: What's the point of `const_cast<const MyList&>(list)`

Comment: The `const` specifier on arguments is a guarantee to the caller that the function will not change the data passed into it. It is not a requirement of the data to be passed in. You can pass in non-const data. So your `const_cast<const MyList&>(list)` is pointless. Also, returning `const MyObject*` from `findObject()` is also pointless. To see why, ponder this snippet: `const int C = 42; int i = C;`

Comment: write it properly and quietly walk away from these childish const_cast ideas. You know why they put safety catches on guns, right?

Comment: `const_cast` is usually a bad idea.

Comment: @SergeyA Avoid infinite recursion?

Comment: @RobK wrong and wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to forget about `const_cast` and just implement both overloads explicitly. **This is what standard-library implementations do.**

For example, `std::vector` has a `const` and non-`const` version of `operator[]`. Both VC++ and GCC have duplicate implementations for that operator (see `include/vector` or `stl_vector.h` files, respectively); neither resorts to any `const_cast` tricks to duplicate the behaviour.

Now, if your `findObject` implementation is very big and complicated, then the first choice should be to make it simpler. As a temporary workaround, you may consider implementing both overloads in terms of an internal (private or otherwise inaccessible) template function, using a `decltype` trailing return type to get the correct `const` or non-`const` return type via the argument. Here is a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo> // just to demonstrate what's going on

// simple example data structure:
struct MyObject {};
struct MyList
{
    MyObject elements[3] = { MyObject {}, MyObject {}, MyObject {} };
};

namespace internal
{
    // &list.elements[0] will be either MyObject const* or MyObject*
    template <class ConstOrNonConstList>
    auto doFindObject(ConstOrNonConstList& list) -> std::vector<decltype(&list.elements[0])>
    {
        // let's say there was an immensely complicated function here,
        // with a lot of error potential and maintenance nightmares
        // lurking behind a simple copy & paste solution...

        // just to demonstrate what's going:
        std::cout << typeid(decltype(&list.elements[0])).name() << "\n";

        std::vector<decltype(&list.elements[0])> result;
        for (auto&& element : list.elements)
        {
            result.push_back(&element);
        }
        return result;
    }
}

std::vector<const MyObject*> findObject(const MyList& list)
{
    std::cout << "const version\n";
    return internal::doFindObject(list);
}

std::vector<MyObject*> findObject(MyList& list)
{
    std::cout << "non-const version\n";
    return internal::doFindObject(list);
}

int main()
{
    MyList list1;
    MyList const list2;
    auto obj1 = findObject(list1);
    auto obj2 = findObject(list2);
}
```

Example output (depending on what kind of names `typeid` produces on your implementation):

```
non-const version
struct MyObject *
const version
struct MyObject const *
```

But frankly, I would not do this. It seems over-engineered, and it's perhaps a bit too clever. Overly clever code is rarely a good idea, because it confuses people.

Comment: This technique is borrowed from Scott Meyer's Effective C++. If library designers avoid it, what are its downsides then? I really can't see any thus far. It's also not possible/advisable to always rework an entire method even if it is too big. Consider dealing with tested legacy code for example. And still, even if it's in the end just bounds checking and other basics, I prefer to have it done once and used twice, instead of having it duplicated in two spots and rely on the developer to synchronize both if he makes changes (practical experience shows: he will frequently not)

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

If you are willing to pay the loop + copy price (vs. copy-pasting code) :

```
std::vector<const thing*> c_vec = static_cast<const me*>(this)->my_const_func();
std::vector<thing*> ret;

for (const thing* t : c_vec) {
    // Yes you can do this, since this func isn't const
    // so you are guaranteed to be inside non-const context.
    // See Scott Meyers.

    ret.push_back(const_cast<thing*>(t));
}
return ret;
```

**Option 2**

[edit] Here is another alternative if you do not want to pay the loop + copy price.

Assuming you are working with a cpp file (not header-only). Inside your compile unit (.cpp), add a templated getter.

```
template <class T, class MyObj>
std::vector<T*> getter_imp(MyObj& obj, int someval) {
    assert(someval <= 42);

    std::vector<T*> ret;
    for (auto& i : obj._my_vec) {
        if (i < someval) {
            ret.push_back(&i);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

To keep things clean and "hidden", you can friend that function in your class.

```
template <class T, class MyObj>
friend std::vector<T*> getter_imp(MyObj&, int);
```

Now, you can call the getter from both const and non-const member functions. Without copy-paste (aka the bane of our lives).

```
std::vector<const int*> get(int v) const {
    return getter_imp<const int>(*this, v);
}
std::vector<int*> get(int v) {
    return getter_imp<int>(*this, v);
}
```

Whats happening here?

You are encoding `const` inside templated arguments. Lets say you call from the `const` function, `T = const int` and `MyObj = const your_class`. Inside the function, `const` gets deduced into `auto&` as well.

When calling from a non-`const` context, the template arguments and `auto&` aren't `const`. So it works.